# Authentication problem on some mobile device

Tags: java, android, authentication, retrofit2

I have a login system on Android, the problem is that some mobiles can identify themselves and the others can't, but there is no error report.

```
private void LogUser() {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
        dialog.show();

        String email = this.Editemail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = this.Editpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<User> call = apiInterface.LogUser(email,password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response)
            {
                if (response.body().getResponse().equals("ok"))
                {
                    SaveSharedPreference.setLoggedIn(getApplicationContext(), true);
                    downloadCatalogue();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }else if (response.body().getResponse().equals("failed"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email ou mot de passe ne correspond à aucun compte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Echec d'authantification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you please share some more code like your ApiClient class and exact error if you're getting so that make us easier to understand

Comment: Try to change this "else if (response.body().getResponse().equals("failed"))" to just else to get all responses from the server which isn't "ok" to your toaster. Then you should see if the server responds with something unexpected.

Comment: Are you trying to execute this method in dialogue box ??

Comment: try this line of code if (response.body().getResponse().equalsIgnoreCase("ok")

Comment: ok thanks. there's no error but it works on other devices but the others don't yet

Answer (score 0):

here is my ApiClieny code

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://IP:port/***/";
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    if (retrofit ==null){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

and ApiService code

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login.php")
Call<User>LogUser(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password
);
```

There is no error that is displayed because I have 5 mobile and the 3 mobile can authenticate and the other two can not identify .